# textInput with submitButton in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently exploring the possibility of visualizing the outputs obtained from rtweet in a shiny dashboard to allow users to explore their own searches. My current blocker is the steps that are needed from the user writing the desired search and making the request via the submit button.

My first attempt was to create a reactive event but that resulted in the query being made every time there were changes in the text box. What would be the best approach to write the request and receive the visualization *after* the submit button is hit?

Bonus, how can I space the area between Query and Submit buttons so they don't look so cluttered on the left side?

Thanks for the pointers!

Code in progress:

```
library(shiny)
library(rtweet)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(
        inputId = "hash",
        label = "Query"
      ),
      submitButton(
        text = "Submit"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("Frequency")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  results <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    search_tweets(
      q = input$hash,
      n = 100)
  })

  output$Frequency <- renderPlot({
    ts_plot(results(), "day")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `eventReactive`.

I have replaced `search_tweets` function with `rnorm` and `ts_plot` with simple `plot` for demonstration purpose.

```
library(shiny)
library(rtweet)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(
        inputId = "hash",
        label = "Query"
      ),
      br(),br(),
      actionButton("submit",
        "Submit"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("Frequency")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  results <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    rnorm(input$hash)
  })
    output$Frequency <- renderPlot({
      plot(results())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ronak, I went ahead and updated the code with your suggestions. I am not receiving any errors when I run it but the query is not being made, am I making a mistake when calling the results() to plot? Thanks!

Comment: Notice I have also replaced `submitButton` with `actionButton` in my answer.

Comment: Gotcha, that went overlooked! Im now getting plotting issues but the information is being captured so just gonna work on that. Thanks again